# Variable indirection in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins system configuration page, I have 3 variables defined, namely, `sandbox_deployed`, `staging_deployed`, and `production_deployed`. In my pipeline, I want to access one of these variables, based on a pipeline property, `BUILD_ENV`, defined in the job's configuration page. **In other words**, in my job's configuration page I have

```
BUILD_ENV=sandbox
```

How can I write pipeline code that does

```
println "$env.${env.BUILD_ENV}_deployed"
```

If I write it like in the above `println`, I get

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@336841dd.sandbox_deployed
```

But I really want this

```
println "env.sandbox_deployed"
```

which prints out the correct value of the `sandbox_deployed` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, at least it worked for me

```
println "${env."${env.BUILD_ENV}_deployed"}"
```